# Hive Transactions + Remote Metastore Error

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm running Hive 2.1.1 on EMR 5.5.0 with a remote mysql metastore DB. I need to enable transactions on hive, but when I follow the configuration [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions#HiveTransactions-Configuration) and run any query, I get the following error

> FAILED: Error in acquiring locks: Error communicating with the metastore

Settings on the metastore:

```
hive.compactor.worker.threads = 0
hive.compactor.initiator.on = true
```

Settings in the hive client:

```
SET hive.support.concurrency=true;
SET hive.enforce.bucketing=true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
SET hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;
```

This only happens when I set `hive.txn.manager`, so my hive metastore is definitely online.

I've tried some of the old suggestions of turning hive test features on which didn't work, but I don't think this is a test feature anymore. I can't turn off concurrency as a similar post in SO suggests because I need concurrency. It seems like the problem is that either DbTxnManager isn't getting the remote metastore connection info properly from hive config or the mysqldb is missing some tables required by DbTxnManager. I have `datanucleus.autoCreateTables=true`.

Comment: The only class that I can find that implements HiveTxnManager is DbTxnManager which is the class that's not working for me. I have an alternative which would be to write a custom transaction manager, but that's not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like hive wasn't properly creating the tables needed for the transaction manager. I'm not sure where it was getting its schema, but it was definitely wrong.

So we just ran the hive-txn-schema query to setup the schema manually. We'll do this at the start of any of our clusters from now on.

https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/metastore/scripts/upgrade/mysql/hive-txn-schema-2.1.0.mysql.sql

Comment: It turns out that this was a bad plan. Changing the schemas manually did work, but as soon as you run any schema migration scripts for hive for version changes, these manually created tables won't be taken into account. The correct approach would have been to figure out what setting hive looks at when determining if it will add transactional tables and let hive handle creating the schema

Answer (score 0):

The error from 
FAILED: Error in acquiring locks: Error communicating with the metastore

sometimes because of it without any data,  you need to initialization some data in your tables. for example below.

```
create table t1(id int, name string)     
clustered by (id) into 8 buckets     
stored as orc TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true');
```